# Using Google Volley with Apache HttpClient 4.2

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-volley

I have had some problems using HttpURLConnection before and the app I'm developing is >= 4.0. Is there any way to use the Apache 4.2 HttpClient (repackaged [here](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/)) with Google Volley?

Currently I am using only the Apache 4.2 HttpClient but with the IO presentation of Volley I want to switch for speed and stability reasons.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in the presentation he said it is possible to wrap a custom http client, so I guess yes.

Comment: I've seen some examples but nothing of use. Can you show a code example? Thanks

Comment: IMO ... either what u have or 'loopj' may actually be better than volley depending on what u r moving across the conn. http://loopj.com/android-async-http/  Me? I do alot of data type file uploads with related JSON refs to the data, and volley/ okhttp do not seem to be there yet with binary entities or file entities.

Comment: @RobertRowntree I do not do any file uploads so that is not relevant for me. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: @RobertRowntree : I haven't used Volley yet, but I understand it's for file entities (images, etc.); you seem to suggest loopj does a better job. Did you mean to favor loopj for uploads, or am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: i have not looked at volley in awhile. You should take a fresh look.

Comment: @JohanS Volley uses HttpUrlConnection internally.  So you can just use Volley for all of your networking code, and ditch HttpClient altogether.  Unless you have a compelling reason to keep using HttpClient?

Comment: Yo Igor, the post is a year old, solved and accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are instantiating your queue use the below one.

```
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity(), new ApacheStack());
```

And then implement an ApacheStack that extends HurlStack like below and Override necessary functions.

```
public class ApacheStack extends HurlStack {

    private final HttpClient client;

    public ApacheStack() {
        this(new HttpClient());
    }

    public ApacheStack(HttpClient client) {
        if (client == null) {
          throw new NullPointerException("Client must not be null.");
        }
        this.client = client;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer! Clean and simple

Comment: You should also override all the methods of HurlStack.

Comment: I am using OkHttp instead of HTTPUrlConnection and Apache. It is from Square Inc and it is very good. You should try it.

Comment: I was thinking to use OkHttp but I had some earlier problems with 401's from our server with HttpURLConnection and we don't use any SPDY stuff or anything. We are also closing in on a production deadline, so I'm gonna stay off OkHttp for a while, but in the future it sounds very promising, I'm already using Picasso for image downloading, fantastic lib from Square aswell. Thanks for the hint though!

Answer (score 2):

The following should suffice:

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, new HttpClientStack(new DefaultHttpClient()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer has an error. It should extent the HttpClientStack rather than the HurlStack. The passed in httpclient is not used if extending the HUrlStack.  You can check the PerformRequest method inside the Volley library and find that the client is not used.

Below is the correct code to do it.

```
public class ApacheStack extends HttpClientStack {

    private final HttpClient client;

    public ApacheStack(HttpClient client) {
        super(client);
        ....

    }
}
```